# Phosphorus particle experiment

Tags: particle-physics

Has anyone ever done an experiment using phosphorus light in complete darkness and in a vacuum to see position and speed of a particle? If casting light on the particles to measure them and know their position disturbs them enough to cancel out the measuring, then would making the particle glow and the path it travels and the thing it hits able to track the phosphorus particle. Is this possible? Has it been done?

Comment: I like the question, in the sense of a facebook like :-) Still, it is a bit forum-like, invites more to discussion of particle detectors than to straight answers.

Answer (score 0):

The history of attempting to solve, overcome the conundrum that wave particle duality presents is fraught with inventive thought experiments. But in every case a fault has been found in the reasoning. In your proposed experiment you define a phosphorus 'particle' that's able to illuminate itself, and thus no interference involved in observing the particle as it travels say through the double slit experiment.

But as with the other thought experiments, there is at least one flaw.

The phosphorus does not emit light spontaneously without first absorbing energy from another photon. Photons in the IR range (heat) excite the phosphorus, and that's what leads the phosphorus to emit a photon in the visible light range. So you actually have at least three particles involved in the process of observing the position, momentum of the phosphorus particle. And all those particles are affected by uncertainty.